# Column and row values to be added parallelly and displayed at the end of each row and each column in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have dynamically created no-of rows and no-of columns based on the requirement using for loops.

```
     for (i = 0; i < a ; i++) {
           $("table").append("<tr id='tr" + i + "'></tr>");
      for (j = 0; j < b ; j++) {
            $('[id^="tr' + i + '"]').append("<td><input type='text' class='add1' id='textbox" + i + "" + j + "'/></td>");
         }
       }
```

i have tried using **blur** event along with **live** like below

```
      $(document).live("input.add1", "blur", function (event) {

          });
```

i have to print addition after each row and column.
please help

with regards

Ramu

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to hide cells or add input values together?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

use **Delegate** instead of **live**

```
     $(document).delegate("input.add1", "blur", function (event) {
      });
```

because **delegate** ..The **.delegate()** method behaves in a similar fashion to the **.live()** method, but instead of attaching the selector/event information to the document, you can choose where it is anchored. Just like the **.live()** method, this technique uses event delegation to work correctly.

**Example :if you write function for ROW Addition then you can have code like below**

```
     $('[id=""]').each(function () {
        Addition($(this).val());
      });
```

Similarly you can use same **Addition** function for COLUMN addition.

All the best

Answer (score 0):

`.live()` is deprecated, use the new `.on()` method as is the prefered way to do event delegation as you want to do, like this:

```
 $(document).on("blur", "input.add1", function (event) {
       //your code
 });
```